# Inkscape groups/layers generation with Cairo/Pycairo SVG?

Tags: python, svg, cairo, inkscape, pycairo

I'd like to be able to add objects (filled rectangles, outlines, etc.) to a cairo SVG context in such a way that when I open the SVG file with Inkscape, each would be recognized as an individual object so that I can move/edit it. Ideally, I'd also like to group objects that would appear as "layers" in Inkscape.

Is this possible to do through the cairo API (to some extent), or would I have to generate each element individually, and then stitch them all together to an Inkscape SVG format? Maybe cairo is not the right tool here? What's the best approach, then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cairo provides an API for *rendering* SVG, but not for generating it.

SVG is just XML, so you could use any off-the-shelf XML library to generate your SVG content. If the content is fairly simple, and you would like a python-based solution, I would recommend [lxml](http://lxml.de/). In this case, you would be using Python's [ETree](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) API to generate XML content.

On the other hand, if the content you're generating is complex, such that you need to position elements dynamically, compute bounding boxes of groups and/or text, and other complex tasks, then I would recommend [Batik](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/), which implement's the SVG DOM and provides such methods. In this case, you would be using the DOM API to generate content. Here are some resources on DOM:

- http://www.w3.org/DOM/DOMTR
- Java DOM bindings: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/package-summary.html
- SVG extensions to DOM: http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/svgdom.html

Batik is written in Java, and so the most straightforward approach would be to use Java to develop against it, but you could also use [Jython](http://www.jython.org/), which is Python for Java, if you prefer to stick with the python language.

Comment: thanks. Yes, I'd like to keep with Python, and eventually the content will be quite complex -- I'm just starting out with simple objects in order to explore the possibilities and see what's the best approach for achieving what I'm after.

Comment: Cairo can also generate SVGs: http://cairographics.org/manual/cairo-SVG-Surfaces.html (but as you see, that API doesn't do what's needed here)

Comment: It’s actually the opposite. Cairo can generate SVG but not render it (unless you have an additional library like rsvg or CairoSVG.)
But yes, it’s maybe not the right tool if you want control on the generated XML.